# Connection to postgresql on EC2 from heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, amazon-ec2

I have problems connecting to an external Postgresql database on EC2 from my heroku app. The problem seams to be with the permission on EC2.

I have done the following:
- added 098166147350/default for my security group on port 5432 (my postgresql port)
- connect to the site using the "Public DNS"-address (ec2-x-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com).

The database I try to connect to is in the EU and not US-East region as the heroku app, don't know if this makes any difference?

Anyway if I add 0.0.0.0/0 to 5432 it does work, so I guess it got to have to be the security settings.

Anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Error messages? contents of PostgreSQL log files on the EC2 machine? When you say "add 0.0.0.0" do you mean in `pg_hba.conf`? Some firewall configuration? Security rules on EC2? On Heroku? Specifics and details please.

Comment: BTW, EC2 tends to perform pretty badly for PostgreSQL because of very poor disk I/O performance. It can be OK for read-mostly workloads if the EC2 instance has enough RAM to cache the whole database, but otherwise it'll be pretty lacklustre. Why not just use Heroku's own Pg hosting?

Comment: I added 0.0.0.0/0 in EC2 security settings. I do use herokus pg hosting. I just need to connect to this database to collect some addition information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got back from heroku support:
Apparently the different i region (us-east (heroku) -> eu (my db)) makes a different in adding a security group like that. So the they suggested a VPN tunnel from us-east on my account to eu. Or just 0.0.0.0/0 and rely on SSL and good passwords.